# Can't get MongoDB working with Spring Security

Tags: mongodb, spring-security

I'm trying to replace the default, XML-driven Spring Security mechanism with a customUserDetailsService that uses MongoDB as described [here](http://codesilo.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/mongodb-spring-data-and-spring-security-with-custom-userdetailsservice/), and I keep getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>web-ui</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>web-ui</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.rfcontrols.rm</groupId>
    <artifactId>region-manager-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data Mongo Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

Here's web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2.5.xsd">

<display-name>web-ui</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters  -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters  -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-app-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Processes login/logout (Spring Security authentication) -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security  -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

security-app-context.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/login"
                   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/img/**"
                   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**"
                   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/bootmetro/css/**"
                   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/bootmetro/font/**"
                   access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
                   access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                   access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
                always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <logout/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

mongo-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="itcs" />
</bean>

<!-- To translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes  -->
<context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

MongoUserDetailsService.java and User.java are exactly as shown in the link above (I tried copy/pasting, but the formatting got all screwy).  For some reason the last closing tag in those XML files is being clipped out when I copy/paste, but they DO exist in the actual files.

EDIT: Here's the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:27)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.rfcontrols.rm.users.MongoUserDetailsService.setMongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo/mongo-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 83 more
```

Comment: Expand your stacktrace, please. And do you really use `DispatcherServlet` only for `/login`-prefixed urls (`web.xml` looks a bit strange)?

Comment: Okay, I added more of the stack trace (the full output exceeds the character limit)...

Comment: And yes, I'm only using DispatcherServlet for the login page, since the app is already using Backbone.js as the MVC.  The security-app-context.xml is capturing URLs at the root, and redirecting to /login when the user hasn't yet been authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root of the problem.  One of the parent POMs was declaring an org.springframework.data dependency version that was different from the version declared in the web-ui POM.  Made them match, and that particular error went away (now I just have new ones to tackle that appear to have to do with log4j and/or slf4j).